# Jersey can't find my resource when the request is wrapped by my filter. Works fine from the browser

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, filter, jersey, jax-rs

I'm using Tomcat (7.0.8x) and Jersey (2.25.1).
As part of a POC, I've written a Filter to intercept some client requests and forward them, after changing the requestURI, to a Jax-RS resource.
The incoming requests are not REST but simple POST requests, that expect JSON response.
My filter, modifies the request uri, targetting a JAX-RS resource.
The problem is that requests that get modified by the filter result in 404 "The requested resource is not available", but if i enter the request that my filter is supposed to produce, from the browser or Postman it works fine.

So the filter is not doing all that it should and I'm here looking for some insight.

The initial target resource is a simple code i copied from some where:
(note that from the browser the request works with the @Produces commented or not, and it does not work with my filter, whether the @Produces is commented or not)

```
package com.test;

//a bunch of imports 
@Path("/helloworld")
public class HelloWorld {

    @GET //this works w/o the filter with the line below commented or uncommented but does not work 
    //@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String sayJsonHello() {
        return "{ \"status\": \"json\" }";
    }

    @POST
    //@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public String sayJsonPostHello() {
        System.out.println(" in sayHello()");
        return "{ \"status\": \"OKAY\" }";
    }

}
```

The context path is "\foo".
My Filter is supposed to convert the POST request
http://localhost:8080/foo/dispatcher/controller/action
to
http://localhost:8080/foo/newdispatcher/helloworld

As I said above, Jersey does not have a problem if i enter this target request in the browser (get), or a POST request via Postman.

My Filter, starts as follows:

```
package com.test;

//a bunch of imports

@WebFilter(filterName = "ombFilter")    
public class OmbFilter  implements Filter {
```

The filter, upon detecting the request that needs to be replaced, creates a HttpServletRequestWrapper and forwards it:

```
servletRequest = new RedirectHttpServletRequestWrapper(request);
servletRequest.getRequestDispatcher("/helloworld").forward(servletRequest, servletResponse);
```

The wrapper is implemented as follows (simplified):

```
class RedirectHttpServletRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
        public RedirectHttpServletRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) {
            super(request);             
        }

        //tried with and without this
        //@Override public String getMethod() { return "GET"; }

        @Override public String getPathInfo() { return "/helloworld"; }

        @Override public String getRequestURI() {   
            return "/foo/newdispatcher/helloworld";
        }

        @Override
        public StringBuffer getRequestURL() {
            return new StringBuffer(
               "http://localhost:8080/foo/newdispatcher/helloworld");
        }

        @Override public String getServletPath() { return "/newdispatcher"; }
    }
```

The web.xml contains the following:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RESTful Jersey Hello World Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.test</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RESTful Jersey Hello World Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/newdispatcher/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- can this be causing the problem? -->
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ombFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/dispatcher/controller/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Update:
Since the client sending the request which My filter is "redirecting", may be different than the browser/Postman, Here are some of the request headers that the client is sending with the request:

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:220
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Would any of these cause Jax-RS to fail in matching this request to the methods in my resource class HelloWorld?
Perhaps I need to add some more/different annotations to the methods there such as @Consumes? (tried @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED) because of the request Content-Type)
Is the Accept-Encoding header the problem?

Comment: Perhaps the difference (between browser/Postman and my client+filter) may be resolved if I added some @Consumes? different @Produces?

Comment: Why are you using a Servlet filter. Could you not just use a JAX-RS Filter?

Comment: vikarjramun I'm trying to transform a subset of non-REST URIs to REST-API request, to then be handled by JAX-RS